FFmpeg does not detect bitstream filter parameter
I have tried to make a bitstream filter for FFmpeg that drops the nth keyframe for positive numbers and allows the first n keyframes and drops the rest for nonpositive numbers, called "datamosh":
ffmpeg -i input.webm -bsf:v datamosh=target=20 -c copy output.webm

outputs the error:
Option 'target' not found
[vost#0:0/copy @ 0x54edc40] Error parsing bitstream filter sequence 'datamosh=target=20': Option not found

Here is the code for the "datamosh" bitstream filter:
#include "bsf.h"
#include "bsf_internal.h"

#include "libavutil/opt.h"

typedef struct {
    const AVClass *class;

    int target, i;
} DatamoshContext;

static int datamosh_init(AVBSFContext *ctx)
{
    DatamoshContext *s = ctx->priv_data;

    s->i = 0;

    return 0;
}

static int datamosh(AVBSFContext *ctx, AVPacket *pkt)
{
    DatamoshContext *s = ctx->priv_data;
    int ret;

    ret = ff_bsf_get_packet_ref(ctx, pkt);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;

    if (s->target < 1) {
        if (s->i <= -s->target)
            return 0;
        else {
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
            return AVERROR(EAGAIN);
        }
    }

    if (pkt->flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY)
        ++s->i;

    if (s->i == s->target) {
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
        return AVERROR(EAGAIN);
    }

    return 0;
}


#define OFFSET(x) offsetof(DatamoshContext, x)
#define FLAGS (AV_OPT_FLAG_VIDEO_PARAM|AV_OPT_FLAG_AUDIO_PARAM|AV_OPT_FLAG_BSF_PARAM)

static const AVOption options[] = {
    { "target", NULL, OFFSET(target), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, { .i64 = 0 }, -INT_MAX, INT_MAX, FLAGS },
    { NULL },
};

static const AVClass datamosh_class = {
    .class_name = "datamosh",
    .item_name = av_default_item_name,
    .option = options,
    .version = LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_INT,
};

const FFBitStreamFilter ff_datamosh_bsf = {
    .p.name = "datamosh",
    .p.priv_class = &datamosh_class,
    .priv_data_size = sizeof(DatamoshContext),
    .init = datamosh_init,
    .filter = datamosh,
};

n is called "target" in the code.
Weirdly, ffmpeg -h bsf=datamosh prints:
Bit stream filter datamosh
datamosh AVOptions:
  -target            <int>        ...VA...B.. (from -2.14748e+09 to INT_MAX) (default 0)


You haven't defined an offset for the option.

@Gyan even with "OFFSET(target)", the same error happens.

Do other filters work this way? -target 20 is the same as =target=20 ?  I think dshow does its own funky processing LOL

@rogerdpack No, I tested that and -target 20 in a generic sense does not work on bitstream filter it must be =parameter=value. The documentation shown is weird.

Declare a class at the top of the context and check: const AVClass *class;

@Gyan Thanks! There is now no error message but it appears to be like the null bitstream filter now, which is not intended but this is an improvement.

BTW, you can just use the noise bsf for datamoshing.

@Gyan why did that help? :)

@Gyan May I have your permission to license this code with your modifications under LGPL 2.1 with an "or any later version" clause and send this as a patch to ffmpeg-devel? I can even add Copyright (c) 2024 Gyan Doshi <ffmpeg@gyani.pro> on your behalf if you like.

Sure. No need for the credit.

I have fixed my code. There were problems with dropping packets properly. Here is the fix:
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "bsf.h"
#include "bsf_internal.h"

#include "libavutil/opt.h"

typedef struct {
    const AVClass *class;

    int target, i;
} DatamoshContext;

static int datamosh_init(AVBSFContext *ctx)
{
    DatamoshContext *s = ctx->priv_data;

    s->i = 0;

    return 0;
}

static int datamosh(AVBSFContext *ctx, AVPacket *pkt)
{
    DatamoshContext *s = ctx->priv_data;
    bool key;
    int ret;

    ret = ff_bsf_get_packet_ref(ctx, pkt);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;

    key = pkt->flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    if (key)
        ++s->i;

    if (s->target < 1) {
        if (s->i <= -s->target)
            return 0;
        else if (key) {
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
            return AVERROR(EAGAIN);
        }
    }

    if (key && s->i == s->target) {
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
        return AVERROR(EAGAIN);
    }

    return 0;
}


#define OFFSET(x) offsetof(DatamoshContext, x)
#define FLAGS (AV_OPT_FLAG_VIDEO_PARAM|AV_OPT_FLAG_AUDIO_PARAM|AV_OPT_FLAG_BSF_PARAM)

static const AVOption options[] = {
    { "target", NULL, OFFSET(target), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, { .i64 = 0 }, -INT_MAX, INT_MAX, FLAGS },
    { NULL },
};

static const AVClass datamosh_class = {
    .class_name = "datamosh",
    .item_name = av_default_item_name,
    .option = options,
    .version = LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_INT,
};

const FFBitStreamFilter ff_datamosh_bsf = {
    .p.name = "datamosh",
    .p.priv_class = &datamosh_class,
    .priv_data_size = sizeof(DatamoshContext),
    .init = datamosh_init,
    .filter = datamosh,
};

